# postfix apparently relay email

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

I have read as many documents as I could understand about tuning postfix main.cf parameters, but still get some external email relayed. Here is a typical example in /var/log/mail.log:

```
Mar  6 06:26:13 myhostname postfix/pickup[21313]: E860B17643B9: uid=33 from=&lt;www-data&gt;
Mar  6 06:26:13 myhostname postfix/cleanup[21605]: E860B17643B9: message-id=&lt;20150306052613.E860B17643B9@mail.mydomain&gt;
Mar  6 06:26:13 myhostname postfix/qmgr[16702]: E860B17643B9: from=&lt;www-data@mydomain&gt;, size=2146, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar  6 06:26:14 myhostname postfix/smtp[21607]: Host offered STARTTLS: [mta5.am0.yahoodns.net]
Mar  6 06:26:16 myhostname postfix/smtp[21607]: E860B17643B9: to=&lt;some_target_address@yahoo.com>, relay=mta5.am0.yahoodns.net[98.138.112.33]:25, delay=2.7, delays=0.05/0/0.4/2.2, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok dirdel)
Mar  6 06:26:16 myhostname postfix/qmgr[16702]: E860B17643B9: removed
```

It occurs about once per hour. However all [these tests](http://www.aupads.org/test-relay.html) pass successfully, ending with **Relay access denied** or **Sender address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table**.

---

The server runs on Debian Wheezy 64, using postfix v2.9.6, dovecot v2.1.7 and spamassassin v3.3.2 (running on Perl v5.14.2).

---

Output of *postconf -n*:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
config_directory = /etc/postfix
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 3
disable_vrfy_command = yes
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 42000000
mydestination = $mydomain, $myhostname, localhost, localhost.$mydomain
mydomain = [obfuscated]
myhostname = mail.[obfuscated]
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]/128, [a few obfuscated trusted IPs]
myorigin = $mydomain
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
relay_domains =
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP
smtpd_client_connection_count_limit = 3
smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit = 60
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 60
smtpd_client_new_tls_session_rate_limit = 60
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_unknown_helo_hostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_client_hostname, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender
smtpd_reject_unlisted_sender = yes
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/loginmaps
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_sender_login_mismatch
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtpd_tls_CApath = /etc/ssl/certs
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = [path to cert file]
smtpd_tls_ciphers = high
smtpd_tls_key_file = [path to key file]
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_address_reject_code = 550
unknown_client_reject_code = 550
unknown_hostname_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_transport = dovecot
```

---

What is wrong ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your web server (www-data) is on the same machine as your postfix and is transmit by the mynetwork directive. If you don't want this, see the scripts, run by Apache, available to see which is sending the email. There is no relaying here

Comment: The web server is indeed on the same machine. However I don't have any yahoo alias (nor any yahoo email account). I deduce that some relay occurred because of the longest line in first extract, ending with "status=sent".

Comment: No relay here, just a PHP (or other) script which send a email

Comment: I use nginx as a web server, and I doubt it would be sending random emails to random recipients at random timestamps =/ EDIT: however, I will try to shut down web server for one night if nothing else seems to work. But I don't understand how I could fix the problem then (the web server is useful :) )

Comment: This looks like someone has found a vulnerability in your web application and is exploiting it to send email. Can you run a packet capture on port 80 (assuming the site is HTTP) and port 25 to see what web activity is going on and what are the contents of the emails?

Comment: I will do that most probably tomorrow, because I won't have time before. For the moment I just ran tshark -i <ethernet_interface> and see a lot of repeated SSH attempts from the same IP address. So I should at least start by limiting the frequency of SSH connexions :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: It turned out that the IP which sent a lot of repeated requests (about 2 or 3 per seconds) is ...mine. I mean the IP behind my ISP box. I don't understand why so many packets are sent, but I won't worry too much for now. Concerning the packet capture on port 80, I tried for a while this afternoon but nothing appeared. Maybe the problem was solved after shutting a few websites which I wasn't using anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said above in comments, postfix isn't configured as an open relay. Again as said above, there was a vulnerability in one of my nginx websites. The problem was "solved" by shutting down unused websites. The only one which I believe could have been attacked is an empty and unconfigured dokuwiki.

Now I still see connexion attempts like

```
Mar  8 02:17:57 vps78987 postfix/smtpd[5935]: warning: hostname [some_domain] does not resolve to address [some_IP]: Name or service not known
Mar  8 02:17:57 vps78987 postfix/smtpd[5935]: connect from unknown[IP]
Mar  8 02:17:57 vps78987 postfix/smtpd[5935]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[IP]
Mar  8 02:17:57 vps78987 postfix/smtpd[5935]: disconnect from unknown[IP]
```

with or without warning, but there is probably nothing to do against that.

Comment: Why 2 down votes ? Maybe because the title now is misleading. I will change it.

Comment: No need to place **[solved]** word in title. Mark this answer as accepted will sufficient.